# Issue with cron job scheduling

Tags: cron

I am trying to schedule a job every 10 minute during PST hours. What I am trying is:

```
0,10 8-15 * * * /path-to-script
```

But this thing is not working, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Any immediate help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are "PST hours"? That should run `/path-to-script` at 08:00, 08:10, 09:00, 09:10, ..., 15:00, and 15:10 every day. Is that what you intended? Telling us it's "not working" is not particularly helpful; exactly what symptoms do you see? What is this script you're running? Presumably it's not literally `/path-to-script`; are there any other differences between what you've shown us and your actual crontab, and could those differences be significant?

Comment: Hi Keith, Thanks. Yes you are right, I need a job to schedule like at 08:00, 08:10, 09:00, 09:10, ..., 15:00, and 15:10 every day. And not working means, the script is not getting executed at scheduled times. And it a shell script like 0,10 8-15 * * * /home/serverstate.sh

Comment: The cron syntax appears to be correct. It could be a problem with your script. Can you execute the script (by copy-and-pasting the command from your crontab) from a shell prompt? Cron jobs run with restricted set of environment variables; does the script depend on some of the ones that aren't set? Have you tried replacing `/path-to-script` with some simple command like `touch $HOME/the-job-ran`? Incidentally, `/home` is an odd place for a script; usually `/home` only contains users' home directories. And "PST hours" is an odd term.